# Running Sum Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm new to Access and I'm trying to develop my own Inventory Management Database.

I'm trying to make a query that could display a running total of the Inventory on Hand as of a specific date. This is how my table looks:

[image]

It's sorted according to ITEM_ID then TRANDATE in ascending order. I'd like to add a calculated field beside the NET field that would show a running total of the specific ITEM_ID after a specific date. Negative numbers in the NET field represent a sale while the positive ones represent a purchase. I tried using the DSUM function as it is widely recommended in creating a running sum field. My expression is this
`DSum([NET],"InvtyTransT", "[ITEM_ID]=" & [ITEM_ID] And "[TRANDATE]<=#" & [TRANDATE] & "#")`. But it only shows the total of the  NET field (6827) in each record like this:

[image]

What I needed is like this:

[image]

(I used an IF function in excel to compute this)

Please help. I think I might have missed something in my expression. I've tried revising it several times and it would always give me the same wrong answer in every record.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post data as text table so that we can copy.

Answer (score 0):

Try correlated sub-query.

```
SELECT t.*, (SELECT SUM(t2.NET)
        from InvtyTransT as t2
        WHERE (t2.TRANDATE <= t.TRANDATE AND t2.ITEM_ID = t.ITEM_ID)
        ) AS rSUM
FROM InvtyTransT AS t;
```

[image]

Comment: Your query worked as intended. However I still have an issue. It doesn't work on transactions that fall on the same TRANDATE. Instead of showing the NET TOTAL after a transaction, it shows the NET TOTAL FOR THE DAY on every record belonging to the same TRANDATE of a specific ITEM_ID. Please take a look at this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x1rihgwe4qpissf/rsum.png?dl=0

Perhaps a little tweak to the SQL statement would correct this issue? thanks in advance

Comment: @dynamitez In this case you need a Unique ID column may be a `Auto Numer` field will serve your purpose. Otherwise you can achieve running sum in report without any unique id field.

Comment: hello, I used this query and it worked:

SELECT T.ITEM_ID, T.TRANDATE, T.DOC_TYPE, T.REF_NO, T.NetPrice, T.NET, SUM(T2.NET) AS QOH

FROM InvtyTransT AS T INNER JOIN InvtyTransT AS T2 ON ((T2.REF_NO*1)<=(T.REF_NO*1) OR T2.TRANDATE<>T.TRANDATE) AND (T2.TRANDATE<=T.TRANDATE) AND (T2.ITEM_ID=T.ITEM_ID)

GROUP BY T.ITEM_ID, T.TRANDATE, T.DOC_TYPE, T.REF_NO, T.NetPrice, T.NET

ORDER BY T.ITEM_ID, T.TRANDATE, (T.REF_NO*1);

thank you very much for your help